# Object value loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

Im trying to loop with an if statement, where the if statement should skip the null value. But some how it won't recognize the null.

My array object value has this

```
[ { "id": 17, "match_id": 17, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 1, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:53", "score": { "id": 17, "playerOne": "Knud", "playerTwo": "Weise", "setOne": 3, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:53", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:38:21" } }, { "id": 18, "match_id": 18, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 2, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:07", "score": { "id": 18, "playerOne": "Hans", "playerTwo": "Khan", "setOne": 0, "setTwo": 3, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:07", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:42" } }, { "id": 19, "match_id": 19, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 3, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:44:12", "score": { "id": 19, "playerOne": "Preben", "playerTwo": "Gertrud", "setOne": 1, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:44:12", "updated_at": "2020-02-21 12:24:39" } }, { "id": 20, "match_id": 20, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 4, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02", "score": { "id": 20, "playerOne": "Ingvard", "playerTwo": "Oscar", "setOne": 0, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02" } }, { "id": 21, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 5, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 22, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 6, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 23, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 7, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 24, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 8, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null } ]
```

My method is this

```
totalsetsTeamOne(){
                let i;
                let SetOneTotal = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if(this.seedmatches[i]!= null){
                        SetOneTotal += this.seedmatches[i].score.setOne;
                    }
                }
                this.setOneTotal = SetOneTotal;
                console.log(SetOneTotal)
            },
```

My error is this

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOne' of null"
```

Comment: The error means that `this.seedmatches[i].score` is `null`.

Comment: `this.seedmatches[i]` is not the null value, it is the `score` object on one of them.

Comment: It's right there in the array you posted: the last few entries have `"score": null`.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I want to skip the value when the seedmatches[i] is NULL. Butt somehow it wont skip it and thats why I get the error with the setOne, because its null

Comment: @SajidLatif are you not reading the comments or the answer? The problem is that the **score** property of some of the objects is `null`. **Look at the array you yourself posted in the question.**

Comment: @JeremyHarris I have read the comment from the others and the answer is given by sabbir.alam further down. But thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if statement should be

```
 if(this.seedmatches[i] && this.seedmatches[i].score){
      SetOneTotal += this.seedmatches[i].score.setOne;
 }
```

Because you are only checking if there are values in this.seedmatches[i]. But what if there are values in this.seedmatches[i] but this.seedmatches[i].score is null? Therefore, we need to check thoroughly if this.seedmatches[i].score is null also.

Answer (score 3):

Because  "id": 21 and other items have "score":null

Comment: I know. Thats why I want to skip it

Answer (score 2):

You are looking if `this.seedmatches[i]` but not if `this.seedmatches[i].score` is null

Answer (score 0):

This code will work..Try this...

```
totalsetsTeamOne() {
    let i;
    let SetOneTotal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (this.seedmatches[i] && this.seedmatches[i].score !== null) {
            SetOneTotal += seedmatches[i].score.setOne;
        }
    }
    this.setOneTotal = SetOneTotal;
    console.log(SetOneTotal)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions of the calculation, using expressions.

The second uses the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
const data = [ { "id": 17, "match_id": 17, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 1, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:53", "score": { "id": 17, "playerOne": "Knud", "playerTwo": "Weise", "setOne": 3, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:53", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:38:21" } }, { "id": 18, "match_id": 18, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 2, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:07", "score": { "id": 18, "playerOne": "Hans", "playerTwo": "Khan", "setOne": 0, "setTwo": 3, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:07", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:39:42" } }, { "id": 19, "match_id": 19, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 3, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:44:12", "score": { "id": 19, "playerOne": "Preben", "playerTwo": "Gertrud", "setOne": 1, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:44:12", "updated_at": "2020-02-21 12:24:39" } }, { "id": 20, "match_id": 20, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 4, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02", "score": { "id": 20, "playerOne": "Ingvard", "playerTwo": "Oscar", "setOne": 0, "setTwo": 0, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:58:02" } }, { "id": 21, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 5, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 22, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 6, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 23, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 7, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null }, { "id": 24, "match_id": null, "dktournament_id": 10, "seed_match": 8, "created_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "updated_at": "2020-02-11 21:37:47", "score": null } ]

const setOneTotal1 = (arr) => 
    arr.reduce((total, { score }) =>
        ((score && (total += score.setOne)), total), 0)
console.log(setOneTotal1(data))

const setOneTotal2 = (arr) => 
    arr.reduce((total, {score}, _, __, s1 = score?.setOne) => 
        (s1 ? total + s1 : total), 0)
console.log(setOneTotal2(data))
```